# Cucumber - How to run a feature file with multiple Scenario in the same template?

Tags: testng, cucumber-jvm

I've 1 feature file like this

Feature: Swissdec pay slips

```
Scenario Outline:
Given Payslips based on the swissdec example salary item types (and formulas).

Scenario: SwissdecPaySlips01: the employee is in working age and get correct payslip with AHV_DEDUCTION
Given we use employee with name "Peter Bosshard"
    And Company with name "Muster AG"
    And Monthly salary of CHF 100000.00
    And Salary Item Type is attached: 1000, 5000, 9010, 5010
When the payslip for 04.2016 is requested
Then we get a payslip with the following items
    | 1000 | MONTHLY_SALARY                 | 100000.00 |
    | 5000 | GROSS_SALARY                   | 100000.00 |
    | 9010 | AHV_BASIS                      | 100000.00 |
    | 5010 | AHV_DEDDUCTION                 |  -5125.00 |
    And a period from 2016.04.01 to 2016.04.30  

Scenario: SwissdecPaySlips02: the employee is in working age and get correct payslip with AHV_DEDUCTION
Given we use employee with name "Hoang Nguyen"
    And Company with name "Axon Active"
    And Monthly salary of CHF 100000.00
    And Salary Item Type is attached: 1000, 5000, 9010, 5010
When the payslip for 04.2016 is requested
Then we get a payslip with the following items
    | 1000 | MONTHLY_SALARY                 | 100000.00 |
    | 5000 | GROSS_SALARY                   | 100000.00 |
    | 9010 | AHV_BASIS                      | 100000.00 |
    | 5010 | AHV_DEDDUCTION                 |  -5125.00 |
    And a period from 2016.04.01 to 2016.04.30
```

The propblem that, foreach time I run this cucumber test case. Every step:

```
@Given("^we use employee with name \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void we_use_employee_with_name(String employeeName) {
}
```

will be runned 2 times. Because it's matched with 2 steps in 2 Scenarios

How could I run test Scenario by Scenario and Step by Step Up To Down?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

best practice is to use tags for scenario's in feature and execute them using runner classes for example:

@tag1
Scenario:
steps

@tag2
Scenario:
steps

and also if you can explain bit more about the issure will be great

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I already solved my problem. @Ranjith's

Answer (score 0):

This issue was because feature file was not properly referenced even though I gave the file system address.On correcting the glue to just the package name of the feature file,it worked.